# change value of an array element, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to create an array of objects, and if some of them are duplicate,I want to increase some fields like (Votes/Score/Percentage), all good..in dump(I get the edited value,but on last dd ,the array is not modified. There I have all elements.

At the end I have 16 array elements (13 +3 with the same lkp_answer_id), insted of 13.

```
$history = AnswerHistory::where('question_id', '=', $id)->get();
$answers = $history->toArray();
$most_voted = [];
        foreach ($answers as $key => $answer) {
            if (!empty($most_voted)) {
                foreach ($most_voted as $best) {
                    //If value already exists, increase Votes/Score/Percentage
                    if ($best['answer_id'] == $answer['lkp_answer_id']) {
                        $best['Votes']++;
                        $best['Score'] = $best['Score'] + $answer['score'];
                        $best['Percentage'] = substr((($best['Votes'] * 100) / $query->votes), 0, 5);
                        $best['Weight'] = substr((($best['Score'] * 100) / $query->total_scoring), 0, 5);
                        dump($best);  //here the array element is changed (correct)
                    //Else add new array element
                    } else {
                        $most_voted[$key] = [
                            'answer_id' => $answer['lkp_answer_id'],
                            'Votes' => 1,
                            'Score' => $answer['score'],
                            'Percentage' => substr(((1 * 100) / $query->votes), 0, 5),
                            'Weight' => substr((($answer['score'] * 100) / $query->total_scoring), 0, 5),
                        ];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //If $most_voted is null, insert first value
                $most_voted[$key] = [
                    'answer_id' => $answer['lkp_answer_id'],
                    'Votes' => 1,
                    'Score' => $answer['score'],
                    'Percentage' => substr(((1 * 100) / $query->votes), 0, 5),
                    'Weight' => substr((($answer['score'] * 100) / $query->total_scoring), 0, 5),

                ];
            }
        }

        dd($most_voted); //here I have a full list with, even duplicate ones
```

Comment: what is ```$answer``` ? where did you use ```$history``` ?

Comment: I edited the post, but I don't think that it matters. The problem is that  the array element values are not changed at the end..

Comment: Try my code and see it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below and try

```
$history = AnswerHistory::where('question_id', '=', $id)->get();
$answers = $history->toArray();
$most_voted = [];
        foreach ($answers as $key => $answer) {
            if (!empty($most_voted)) {
                foreach ($most_voted as $k => $v) {
                    //If value already exists, increase Votes/Score/Percentage
                    if ($most_voted[$k]['answer_id'] == $answer['lkp_answer_id']) {
                        $most_voted[$k]['Votes']++;
                        $most_voted[$k]['Score'] = $most_voted[$k]['Score'] + $answer['score'];
                        $most_voted[$k]['Percentage'] = substr((($most_voted[$k]['Votes'] * 100) / $query->votes), 0, 5);
                        $most_voted[$k]['Weight'] = substr((($most_voted[$k]['Score'] * 100) / $query->total_scoring), 0, 5);
                        dump($most_voted[$k]);  //here the array element is changed (correct)
                    //Else add new array element
                    } else {
                        $most_voted[$key] = [
                            'answer_id' => $answer['lkp_answer_id'],
                            'Votes' => 1,
                            'Score' => $answer['score'],
                            'Percentage' => substr(((1 * 100) / $query->votes), 0, 5),
                            'Weight' => substr((($answer['score'] * 100) / $query->total_scoring), 0, 5),
                        ];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //If $most_voted is null, insert first value
                $most_voted[$key] = [
                    'answer_id' => $answer['lkp_answer_id'],
                    'Votes' => 1,
                    'Score' => $answer['score'],
                    'Percentage' => substr(((1 * 100) / $query->votes), 0, 5),
                    'Weight' => substr((($answer['score'] * 100) / $query->total_scoring), 0, 5),

                ];
            }
dd($most_voted); //here I have a full list with, even duplicate ones
```

Comment: try again and give the ```dump``` and ```dd``` output.

Comment: I tried with something simple like " $best['Votes'] =12345 , but in the final dd the array is unchanged..

Comment: you try like my code and give the output. Like your above comment didn't work.

Comment: Here is the output: https://codeshare.io/5ZO7oe  , the values are changed now, but I stii get duplicate answer_id ,in array..

Comment: where is duplicate ```answer_id```?

Comment: On 2,18,58. In dd I have one of them changed (correct), and one with initial value. The array must contain 13 elements,at the end.

Comment: can you please give the ```dump($answers)```

Comment: In the above URL from codeshare, is dd for answers.  Under " //FROM DD "

Comment: Please first check my code correctly.  I mentioned ```dd($most_voted);``` . This value have only 13 elements check first and see.

Comment: From where you got ```dd($answers);``` ?

Comment: dd($most_voted) is here (I edited, but still the same 16 elements)  https://codeshare.io/5ZO7oe

Comment: ```$answers = $history->toArray();``` after this put ```dump($answers);``` and give the output.

Comment: Yes, but with duplicates, but is OK, for what I need next it doesn't bother me. Thanks a lot!